# Move multiple divs randomly using jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I use this jQuery fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/BREvn/5/

I am making a bird shooting game with this in each level birds increases which are simply these divs but problem is when i increases these they all are going out of container every time in bottom right position .I want is that divs should only touch the borders of container.

my code is

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <script src="/js/jquery-2.0.2.min.js"></script>
<style>
div#container {height:50%;
                   width:50%;
       border:2px solid white;           



    }
    .a {
width: 120px;
height:120px;

position:relative;

}
</style>

 <script type="text/javascript">
 function randomFromTo(from, to) {
                return Math.floor(Math.random() * (to - from + 1) + from);
            }

            function moveRandom(obj) {
                /* get container position and size
                 * -- access method : cPos.top and cPos.left */
                var cPos = $('#container').offset();
                var cHeight = $('#container').height();
                var cWidth = $('#container').width();

                // get box padding (assume all padding have same value)
                var pad = parseInt($('#container').css('padding-top').replace('px', ''));

                // get movable box size
                var bHeight = obj.height();
                var bWidth = obj.width();

                // set maximum position
                maxY = cHeight ;
                maxX = cWidth;

                // set minimum position
                minY = cPos.top + pad;
                minX = cPos.left + pad;

                // set new position         
                newY = randomFromTo(minY, maxY);
                newX = randomFromTo(minX, maxX);

                obj.animate({
                    top: newY,
                    left: newX
                }, 1000, function () {
                    moveRandom(obj);
                });
            }



            $('.a').each(function () {
                moveRandom($(this));
            });
</script>
</head>
<body>



<div id="container">
        <img src="graphics-birds-917288.gif" class='a'/>
        <img src="graphics-birds-917288.gif" class='a'  />
        <img src="graphics-birds-917288.gif" class='a' />
        <img src="graphics-birds-917288.gif" class='a' />
        <img src="graphics-birds-917288.gif" class='a' />
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I have yet to witness a red box move outside the grey box.

Comment: When you increase what ?

Comment: they look fine in the fiddle.

Answer (score 1):

You have removed an important element

```
maxY = cHeight;
maxX = cWidth;
```

this should be

```
maxY = cPos.top + cHeight - bHeight;
maxX = cPos.left + cWidth - bWidth;
```

At the moment you are allowing the TOP of each image to go to the height of the container - this minor correction means you will go to the height of the container MINUS the height of the object

In the fiddle this is still included (+ padding but that isnt necessary with your example) but you have removed them in your code for some reason!

Comment: Oh sorry but I added that still it going out of the box in bottom right.